# remote desktop & launcher (.exe)

Tags: launcher, remote-desktop

1) What are clear steps for being able to remote into my Ubuntu box from my Windows 7 box?

2) Is there a way to have a .exe be attached to my left-hand launch bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install `xrdp` in Ubuntu. Open a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal), then run below
  command:

> ```
> sudo apt-get install xrdp
> ```

- Open Remote Desktop Connection in Windows 7 (click **Start** button,
  then search “remote” in search box).

[image: RDC]

- Input the host name or IP address of your Ubuntu machine, then click
  **Connect**.

[image: RDC]

- Input your username and password of Ubuntu, then click **Ok** to
  connect.

[image: RDC]

**Source**: http://www.ubuntututorials.com/remote-desktop-ubuntu-12-04-windows-7/

Comment: @Radu - if you based your answer on this site http://www.ubuntututorials.com/remote-desktop-ubuntu-12-04-windows-7/ please provide source link. I don't think ubuntututorials will mind but they sure need the proper source link so they can get the credit.